# A very curious wifi problem

Tags: wifi

I was having some trouble with my wifi reception on the 2.4g band so I started up airodump to look for any offending signals. I found a strong hidden essid on the same channel I was on, so I logged on to my router and switched channel. Curiously the mac transmitting the hidden essid did the same thing. (?) I thought maybe this is someone playing around with a simple script? But what for? So in order to alleviate my wifi issues, I simply engaged the 5g band and logged on to that instead. However, when I engaged the 5g, I then found the same mac address transmitting the same hidden essid on the 5g band! (and no longer on the 2.5g band) I contacted rogers tech support asking them if they were at all aware of how my router would have a third mac address sending out a hidden beacon, but they were as dumbfounded as I am. No other router in the neighborhood is doing the same thing, only mine.

I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on why my router is doing this. Why does it have some third mac sending out a beacon I have zero control over? Why is it only my router, when everyone around me has the same rogers router?

Comment: Do you have a Roku? Their remotes use wifi direct on the same channel as your access point.

Comment: You should be able to use the signal strength to identify the general location of the hidden essid.  If it is coming from your router ... I would upgrade the firmware and/or get a new one (diff brand).